# How do I find out if a web app is running as an Android app or in the Chrome web browser

Tags: javascript, android, css, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I use the SVGOMG-TWA example in Android studio to package a PWA as an Android app. Can I find out if a web page is displayed in the Android app or in the web browser?

The test with `@media all and (display-mode: browser)` returns true in the Android app (Chrome version 72.0.3626.121).